# How to run python script on multiple unix devices

Tags: python

I've python script that logs into unix device, creates a file and reboot the device. Currently it takes device IP as argument and can run on single device e.g.

```
python testdevice.py <device ip>
```

**Que:** How to make this script run on multiple devices in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this not work?

```
python testdevice.py <device ip> & python testdevice.py <device ip>
# keep repeating for however many devices you have
```

You would give a different device IP to each call.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to automate while dealing with multiple computers is to use one of the IT-Automation Tools such as [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/). That gives a general solution and not restricted to python.
To do what you need to:
- define your hosts ips in your [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) file.
- write a playbook to execute a command on the remote nodes, which is explained in [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html), for example:

```
- command: ./my-script.py
  args:
    chdir: somedir/
    creates: /path/to/database
```